# Question about definition of the limit of a sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

If $(x_n)$ is a sequence, and $x$ is the limit, provided that it exists, in the definition, we have a part where $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$.

Now we also have a theorem:

> If $a\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $0\le{a}<\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$,
>   then $a=0$.

Why can't we compare $a=|x_n-x|$ and therefore conclude that $|x_n-x|=0,\forall{n}\ge{K(\epsilon)}$ ?

In my textbook, the said theorem is used to prove the uniqueness of limit. So why won't the same property apply in the definition?

---

Edit: I corrected my condition of $n$, which I by mistake wrote $\forall{n}\in\Bbb{N}$.

Comment: Perhaps you should be able to find the difference between the inequality used in definition of limit and the inequality used in the theorem. The theorem deals with one particular number $a$ and all $\epsilon>0$. The expression $|x_n-x|$ in limit definition is not one particular number but changes with $n$. If it were so (for example a constant sequence) then the theorem applies.

Answer (score 2):

In your theorem about $0 \leq a < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$, the constant $a$ does not change.  That is, $a$ is a particular real number. In contrast, using $a=|x_n-x|$ does not make sense, since the left-hand-side is $a$ (which does not depend on the index $n$) while the right-hand-side is $|x_n-x|$ (which depends on the index $n$).

---

The definition of limit of $x_n$ being a real number $x$ says that for all $\epsilon>0$, the inequality $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$ is true *for all sufficiently large values of the index $n$* (not necessarily for *all* values of $n$).

For example, if $x=0$ and $x_n=1/n$ for $n \in \{1, 2, 3,...\}$, then we have:

- The inequality $|x_n-0|<1/1000$ is true for all $n \in \{1001, 1002, 1003, ...\}$.
- The inequality $|x_n-0|<1/34000$ is true for all $n \in \{34001, 34002, 34003, \ldots\}$.
- In general, the inequality $|x_n-0|<\epsilon$ is true for all integers $n$ that satisfy $n>1/\epsilon$.

So if $x_n=1/n$ for $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$, we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n = 0$.  However, certainly it is not true that $|x_n-0|=0$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.

Comment: True that $a$ is a constant. But if we take several such $a_i$'s for some $i\in{\alpha}$, and assign $|x_n-x|$ for each $n$ to each $a_i$, my question remains the same. The expression $|x_n-x|$ depends on $n$, but each result is a constant. So even if in general the expression is not a constant, each result of the expression is constant, and the theorem should be applied. What am I missing?

Comment: I do not follow your above comment.  Can you write it precisely?  What is the set $\alpha$?  How do you precisely define $a_i$? By "assign $|x_n-x|$ for each $n$ to each $a_i$," I think you really mean to define $a_n = |x_n-x|$ for $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$, correct?

Comment: @Kawrno: the $a$ in theorem is same for all $\epsilon $ but the expression $|x_n-x|$ is not the same for all $\epsilon $. Why do you think the situation in both limit definition and your theorem are same?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: I have just checked the book now, and both the theorem and the definition of convergence of sequence tells that, the condition regarding $\epsilon$ is - "for every $\epsilon>0$". I see this as the same condition for both.

Comment: @Michael: $\alpha$ is just a set of arbitrary indices of $a$, nothing to do with $n$. I learnt this manner of writing from some book on pure mathematics, can't remember. It is just to separate 'one particular $a$' from 'another $a$'. To explain further, say there is a real number $a_5$, such that $0\le{a_5}<\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$, for which, we have $a_5=|x_8-x|$ for every $\epsilon>0$. In the similar fashion, with the similar conditions, let $a_3=|x_9-x|$. I was trying to state the above; $\alpha$ is just the set of $5$, $3$ et cetera.

Comment: If $0\leq a_5 < \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$, then $a_5=0$.  I don't get what connection $a_5$ has to $|x_8-x|$.  You may gain intuition if you try to be more precise.  If $\alpha$ is a finite set of indices then the fact that $x_n$ converges to $x$ says absolutely nothing about the values of $x_i$ for $i \in \alpha$.

Comment: @Kawrno: you should note that the values of $n$ in $|x_n-x|$ depends on $\epsilon $.

Comment: @Kawrno: also the example in your previous comment should help you in clarifying your confusion. If $a_5=|x_8-x|<\epsilon $ for all $\epsilon >0$ then $a_5=0$ and $x_8=x$. But that's not what limit definition is about. The $n$ in $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$ itself is based on $\epsilon$ as $n\geq K(\epsilon) $. Thus the values of $n$ which work for some $\epsilon$ may not work for different value of $\epsilon $. This is something you have overlooked.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, thank you, that helps.